# Factorial of 170+

Tags: php, factorial

everytime I try to get the factorial of 171, I get INF. 170 works fine. Is it possible to get the factorial of 171+ in a script? How?
My function:

```
function factorial($n) {
    if ($n == 0) return 1;
    return $n * factorial($n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to use [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [GNU MP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extension. PHP doesn't provide any tools for high-values or high-precision operations OOTB.

Answer (score 10):

If you deal with very large numbers, you'll need to use an extension that allows you to do that.

There's BCMath ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) , and GMP ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php ).

Comment: The GNU MP extension even offer a `gmp_fact()` function to compute large factorials out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "1241018070217667823424840524103103992616605577501693185388951803611996075221691752992751978120487585576464959501670387052809889858690710767331242032218484364310473577889968548278290754541561964852153468318044293239598173696899657235903947616152278558180061176365108428800000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

really though, your function is fine.  I think PHP lacks that kind of precision.  I got the value (it is correct btw) in python

Comment: I don't need the 171 factorial, I need the script, which could count that :)

Comment: open up terminal.  type 'python' type 'import math' type 'math.factorial(171)'.  you can't do it in PHP without an extension like @Crozin and @EboMike mentioned

Comment: lol, yes. A calculator actually beats a search engine at math. Go figure.

Comment: You are evil.  But +1

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting a value that exceeds the maximum double precision float in a 32-bit machine (`~10^308`).  170! factorial is `~7.25741562 × 10^307` which is just under that, however, 171! is larger.  Your best bet is to use one of the libraries EboMike or Crozin recommends in their answers.

Answer (score 2):

For large n, you can compute n! very quickly with little error using Stirling's approximation. Take a look at this post; it has an analysis of the function and some sample code:

http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/stirlings-approximation-formula-clojure/

Answer (score 1):

It's a bigger number than you can hold using 32-bits. If you run the same code on a 64-bit computer then it should work.

Comment: Not exactly a very portable solution.

Comment: No, but depending on where the code needs to run it might actually be the easiest.

Comment: A 64-bit computer has a limit too :D... It would just be 2^21 times bigger :P

Comment: Depends on the OS; on Windows, it will always be 32 bits, but on Linux it will be 64 as you suggest.  http://www.pubbs.net/200902/php/3781-re-php-dev-casting-doubles-to-ints.html